# how to set trigger onmouseenter on rectangle

Tags: silverlight

There is a rectangle

```
  <Rectangle Name="rectangle1"
             Width="24"
             Height="288"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Stroke="Transparent"
             StrokeThickness="1" >
```

How to set trigger onmouseenter on rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Fill="Transparent"` to the set of properties on the `Rectangle`.